Animation FBX export problem, It doesn't look same when exported
so i exported the animation for unity but it seems like the animation changes when it is exported as FBX... I've tried many things but nothing seems to fix this problem... i even tried the simplify slider in export settings... need help guys

https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/1g9elkd/animation_fbx_export_problem_it_doesnt_look_same/  for video reference
